# In C++, if a member reference is initialized in its declaration, why does it need storage space?

Tags: c++

Consider this example.

```
struct S
{
    int j;
    inline static int i;
    int &ri{i};
};

S s;

static_assert(sizeof(s) > sizeof(int));

#include <type_traits>

static_assert(!std::is_standard_layout_v<S>);
```

( https://godbolt.org/z/vWFkBC ).  The compiler reserves space for the reference within the class memory layout.  I can't think of an example where a member reference which is initialized in its declaration would clearly be useful.  Perhaps that is why compilers do not optimize for this case.  Or, is there something in the Standard that prohibits optimizing out this reference?

Comment: Do note that `int &ri{i};` is shorthand for telling the compiler to use `i` as the initializer for any constructor that does not initialize `ri`.  There is nothing stopping someone from later on adding a constructor that sets `ri` to refer to something else.  If that happens, `ri` would not be able to be optimized away it would be very surprising that adding a constructor changed the size of the class.

Comment: A somewhat related issue is that, even in non-standard layout classes, compilers don't reorder fields to reduce pad bytes.  https://godbolt.org/z/wp4Tsv

Answer (score 3):

In this class the storage is necessary to keep track at runtime of which object `ri` is bound to, for example:

```
int main()
{
    int foo, bar;

    S s = { 3, rand() % 2 ? foo : bar };

    func(s);  // in other translation unit
}
```

But even if you come up with some other exact case where the program could run without requiring storage for `ri`,  it would mean that the size of the struct changes between different builds when the program undergoes some subtle change (or you use a different `-O` optimization flag) that makes the optimization no longer possible.  This is generally not behaviour that programmers desire, so compilers don't do it.

Also the compiler has to take ABI compatibility into account; it's considered desirable by users for a header file to be used with a binary-only library built by one compiler and incorporated into a project using a different compiler. So the classes specified in the header should have a predictable layout.

You could make a similar argument that the compiler might not allocate storage for `j` so long as it determines the program does not use the value or address of `j` anywhere,  and the response as to why the compiler doesn't actually do that 
would be similar.

Comment: `You could make a similar argument that the compiler might not allocate storage for j so long as it determines the program does not use the value or address of j anywhere, and the response as to why the compiler doesn't actually do that would be similar.` is that really necessarily true? Due to the as-if rule the compiler would be able to remove unused members if that would not result in side effects. So if it is not a library, and removing `j` would not lead to side effects in the application, the compiler could remove it.

Comment: @t.niese yes, I am saying the compiler could remove it due to the as-if rule, but would choose not to due to user expectation

Comment: I know that this is an oversimplified example: [godbolt.org](https://godbolt.org/z/CAwvwR) . But this clearly removes even the `struct` itself. And in the case of libraries, you can tell the compiler which classes you want to export and which not. For those that are exported, the compiler for sure could not do these optimizations, or only in really rare cases.

Comment: @t.niese removing a whole struct is quite different to removing part of a struct

Comment: Fair enough, but your code example becomes moot if ri is not public, thus blocking the override of ri by C-style initialization:  https://godbolt.org/z/f7Q2fP .

Comment: @WaltK that is addressed in my paragraph immediately after the code block